# Threading - Guarantee getting the last result

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, staleobjectstate

I have several threads which call a method. It looks something like this:

```
public void DoWork(params int[] initialConditions)
{
    //Do a lot of work
}
```

However, If conditions are changing quickly, I get a lot of stale intermediate results because I can't finish the calculations quickly enough. I know! I'll modify the code to look like this:

```
public void DoWork(params int[] initialConditions)
{
    if(Monitor.TryEnter(syncLock)
    {
        //Do a lot of work
        Monitor.Exit(syncLock);
    }
}
```

Now I won't bother to do calculations unless my previous calculations are finished. I'll be a little behind in rapidly changing situations, but no more than I would have been, and I won't waste my time doing all that extra work for stale results.

**However,**

Once the situation stops changing, I'm still a little bit out of date, and the final thread that wanted to call DoWork is long gone. Is there a way to tell a thread:

```
if no one is doing work
    do work
else
    wait to do work until after the other thread finishes
but
    if a new thread arrives before you start doing work, leave without doing work.
```

Comment: An Ideal Situation would look about as clean as the Monitor.TryEnter version, but somehow act like the psuedo code version of the code

Comment: So your operations depend on one another ?

Comment: Do work depends on only the initial conditions passed in, but sets some global variables based on what it calculates, so individual thread calls to DoWork don't depend on each other, but they do affect the result of the program as a whole.

Comment: This sounds like a job for `ConcurrentStack<int[]>`.

Comment: Can't you get rid of the global variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should meet your requirements described by pseudo code:

```
class Program
{
    static object _workLockObject = new object();
    static volatile int _currentPriority = 0;

    static void Main()
    {
        Task t1 = new Task(() => TryDoWork(1));
        Task t2 = new Task(() => TryDoWork(2));
        Task t3 = new Task(() => TryDoWork(3));

        t1.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        t2.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        t3.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static void TryDoWork(params int[] initialConditions)
    {
        var priotity = Interlocked.Increment(ref _currentPriority);
        while (!Monitor.TryEnter(_workLockObject))// starting to wait when DoWork is available
        {
            if (priotity != _currentPriority) // if the thread has stale parameters
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DoWork skipped " + initialConditions[0]);
                return;// skipping Dowork
            }
            Thread.Sleep(300);// Change the interval according to your needs
        }
        try // beginning of critical section
        {
            if (priotity == _currentPriority) // if the thread has the newest parameters
                DoWork(initialConditions);
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_workLockObject); // end of critical section
        }
    }
    public static void DoWork(params int[] initialConditions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoWork started " + initialConditions[0]);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("DoWork ended " + initialConditions[0]);
    }
}
```

`Interlocked.Increment` guarantees that every thread has its own priority and the latest thread has a priority that allows to execute `DoWork` when it is available.